# Changing travel to Australia dates after visa issuance

Tags: visas, australia, south-asia

I will be graduating from a university in Australia in the next 6 months and intend on inviting my family over for the graduation ceremony. We are only eligible to apply for Visitor Visa (Subclass 600). The reason for applying the visa would be attending the graduation ceremony and visiting family (me).

My main question basically is can my parents change their travel plans after issuance of the visa? For instance, to visit me after the graduation ceremony instead of attending the ceremony.

At this stage I am not perfectly sure if they would be able to take time off for my graduation dates and if it's all right for them to visit after the graduation dates.

Comment: Has the visa been issued? If so, what dates are on it?

Comment: No the visa has not been rejected. Sorry for not being clear on that. We haven't applied for the visa yet. So this is more of a question to help us plan that. Basically my graduation date falls on mid November and my parents will apply for visa in start of October. The minimum term for this visa(Subclass 600) is 3 months so assuming they get granted the visa the visa will last until January. Are they allowed to travel in December even though the event (my graduation) they applied the visa for falls in November. Please let me know if any of this is not clear and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, your parents can travel as long as the visa is valid.  If they are granted a 3-month visa in October, and travel in December so that they plan to return before the visa runs out in January, that will be fine.

However, your parents may need to explain the change of plans on arrival in Australia.  They should be prepared to explain/show:

- the reason they are visiting now (seeing their child & could not travel earlier is OK)
- demonstrate ties to home country (proof of employment, assets, etc)
- "sufficient" funds for their stay
- return tickets